# how do I move to the next array when the sound has finished playing?

Tags: java, android, arrays, audio

im new here, can you help me? I want when the sound is complete, the imageView will display the next array of images

I have tried using this code but when the sound is finished it exits the application instead

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(home.this, R.raw.decision);

    mediaPlayer.start();

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            next();
        }
    });

}
```

my code :

```
private int image [] = {R.drawable.definisiprisma1, R.drawable.definisiprisma2, R.drawable.definisiprisma3};
private int gambar = 0;
ImageView imageView;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(home.this, R.raw.decision);

    mediaPlayer.start();

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            next();
        }
    });

}

private void next() {
    gambar = gambar % image.length;
    gambar++;
    imageView.setImageResource(image[gambar]);
}
```

how do I move to the next array when the sound has finished playing?

Comment: You forgot to initialize your `ImageView` in to `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your `imageView` by

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id....);
```

in `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

On create is call only first time when screen launch, you can want start again sound .